Instructions for installing eGalax Touch Screen from the command line on Raspberry pi 4b
I need instructions on how to install, configure, calibrate, eGalax Touch Screen. All necessary actions must be done from the command line, replacing and editing files.
definition USB:
root@pi:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax Touch Screen
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@pi:~#

I only found this instruction. But the touchscreen did not respond to pressing.
    sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev x11proto-input-dev
wget http://github.com/downloads/tias/xinp...
tar -zxvf xinput_calibrator-0.7.5.tar.gz
cd xinput_calibrator-0.7.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev xinput-calibrator -y
sudo mv /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/45-evdev.conf

2) /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"                          libinput to "evdev"  !!!
EndSection

3) /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf
----------------------------------------------------------------
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "calibration"
     MatchProduct "eGalax Inc. USB TouchController"
     Option "Calibration" "0 2000 0 2000"         
     Option "SwapAxes" "0"                         
     Option "TransformationMatrix" "-1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1"
EndSection

version:
root@pi:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
root@pi:~# 

root@pi:~# uname -a
Linux pi 6.6.31-v8+ #1766 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 24 12:14:10 BST 2024 aarch64 GNU/Linux


Ask the manufacturer/supplier.

But it didn't work ... what does this mean? ... what happened?

You are running an old OS (Buster) but a 6.6.31-v8+ kernel (presumably with rpi-update despite the warnings).
Re-install the OS - and you might use a current OS!

Will the new system solve the problem with eGalax?

@Aleksey no one can say because you have provided no meaningful details but running a testing kernel is unlikely to help. For some reason beginners seem to think updating a kernel is a good idea.

Then why are you writing about the kernel update? Updating the kernel will not help. What information do you need?
